# Where can I find a lock that can do this?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have two pipes, blue & yellow wherein blue is wider than yellow.

I need something (lock) that will prevent the yellow pipe from falling if the lock is tight, and at the same time is able to loosen so that I can adjust the yellow pipe up or down whenever I want.

What I will hang under the yellow pipe is [computer speaker](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Logitech-usb-speakers.jpg), one in my left and right.

[image]

Speaker Weight:

Left: 239g (8.4oz), Right: 343g (12.1oz)

Comment: I was thinking of rachet and rack mechanism.

Comment: How heavy are those speakers and how thick are the walls of the yellow pipe (how well could it withstand compression)?

Comment: Why not grab the legs off any standard scope/camera tripod?

Comment: But why exactly do you want to change the speaker height? The sound field will not change measurably.

Answer (score 4):

For this problem, I think that the way a bike saddle works would be ideal. You have a slit in the outer pipe, allowing it to bend inwards slightly when tightened to grip the inner pipe. Then you have an adjustable tension ring around the outer pipe, with a quick-release lever to grip with an appropriate pressure.

[image: Diagram of saddle with adjustment mechanism]

You can buy these clamps separately, so it should just be a case of finding the right size of pipes and clamps. A Google search for [seat post quick release clamp](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=seat+post+quick+release+clamp) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind only being able to adjust the pipe in steps, the locks that can often be seen on steel tube scaffolding or medical crutches might be a perfect solution to this problem! Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: https://neeraliparbhu.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/img_8789.jpg]

Otherwise, if the pipe isn't too thin, you might try cutting a thread into the pipes. Unfortunately, these may loosen over time if the fit is too loose or the pitch is too large.

You could also just drill a hole into the side of the outer pipe and put a wingnut through it, this will allow you to adjust on the fly. I don't like these very much because they tend to slip unless you really tighten them up, but then you might crush the pipe on the inside. If the speaker is fairly small, however, it might work.

Comment: can you give me picture of "if the pipe isn't too thin, you might try cutting a thread into the pipes" that you're saying?

Comment: Something like in this picture:

https://cdn.mscdirect.com/global/images/ProductImages/3690308-11.jpg

You would need a fairly long thread to get any range of motion, though.

Comment: Cheap shower curtain rails and telescopic window cleaning booms often use twisting mechanisms which I presume use some sort of threaded compression mechanism, the poles can be twisted at any point of extension and no external twist grip is necessary (but can exist)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like a blockade lock. You might get some idea through [this](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/High-Security-container-push-steel-bolt_60437017946.html?spm=a2700.7724857.0.0.K9tfl3&s=p).

There are a couple of assumptions I am making here. One of them is that is a one-time lock that you need, like the ones they use to seal containers. I don't know how frequently you'll need to separate the two parts. If it is very rarely, like once in an year or so, such locks might do the trick.
My computer speakers are way too heavy (since they are old) for this kind of a lock, but the ones you have linked in the questions, don't really look that heavy. This kind of lock should do the trick for you.